# select:HOVER, apply style to child of :HOVER element not working

Tags: css

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

I have some text elements inside an `<a>` which I want `text-decoration:none` on when the `<a>` is hovered over. See HTML below, which I believe should work, but when I mouseover that `<a>` the text is still underlining child `<h2>` and `<p>`.

**HTML**

```
<a href="" class="link-box">
    <div>
        <span class="icon-stat"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
        <h2>Membership Management</h2>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a.link-box:HOVER h2, a.link-box:HOVER p {
    text-decoration: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Try it

http://jsfiddle.net/L3pxr0tx/

Comment: Bloody hell!  I certainly overcomplicated that one!  Thanks Parfait!